# Linker Command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)?

Tags: xcode8

while Running i face this issue.

Linker Command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)? in xcode 8.3.2.

**I am not using COCOAPODS in my project**

while clicking issue navigator item.For this particular error its not opening.

**Error Screen shot**
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/usJFW.png

Comment: could you post your complete error?

Comment: Error Screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmZ0y.png

Comment: Not this. when you tap on this eror, detail will be shown on right hand side. Post that detail error

Comment: when i am tap on this error, detail will not shown.

Comment: Right-click on the error and choose Reveal in Log. Maybe the error goes away if you fix the other problems.

Comment: Thanks now the error is  showing  on right hand side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions.

- Go to `Compile sources` in `Build Phases`, make sure there is no
  duplicate files and all .m files of your project is there.
- Go to your build settings and switch the target's settings to
      `ENABLE_BITCODE = YES`.
- Try luck with Product -> Clean

Comment: Thanks for your answer.There is no duplicates in my .m files .But still its showing the same error

Comment: Error is related to GoogleMap Framework. Try by deleting existing and add again. Make sure 'Destination' and 'Add to targets' tabs selected